# Open XML Insert in Temp table - SQL 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, insert

I have a stored procedure where i am passing a simple XML:

```
'<Products><ProductId>1</ProductId><ProductId>2</ProductId></Products>'
```

I have a @temp table in SQL which has a ProductId Column:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
ProductId NVARCHAR(10)
)
```

I need to write an insert statement which will loop through the ProductId's in the XML (which can be infinite) and keep on inserting (in the @temp table) until the XML has no more ProductId nodes left.

A solution involving cursors is not feasible!

Following is the code I am trying to execute:

```
Declare @test XML
SET @test = '<Products><ProductId>1</ProductId><ProductId>2</ProductId></Products>'
DECLARE @Temp TABLE(        
    ProductId NVARCHAR(10)
   )  
INSERT INTO @Temp(ProductId)
SELECT tab.col.value('./ProductId[1]','NVARCHAR(10)') AS 'ProductId'
FROM @test
CROSS APPLY
xml_data.nodes('//Products') AS tab(col)
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Must declare the table variable "@test".
```

Comment: Try running just the SELECT portion of the INSERT, swapping out the @test with the xml string.  Make sure that works first

Comment: Won't allow me to do a FROM on a string.

Comment: Yeah, need to use OPENXML - see my updated answer.  Ref: OPENXML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276847%28SQL.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @test XML
    SET @test = '<Products><ProductId>1</ProductId><ProductId>2</ProductId></Products>'

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(ProductId NVARCHAR(10))  

DECLARE @docHandle int 
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @doc 

INSERT INTO @Temp(ProductId)
     SELECT t.value('./ProductId[1]','NVARCHAR(10)') AS 'ProductId'
       FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, '//Products', 1) t

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @docHandle
```

Comment: Just added a standalone code to explain my example still throws an error !

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @idoc int

DECLARE @doc varchar(1000)

SET @doc ='
<OutLookContact>
<Contact FirstName="Asif" LastName="Ghafoor" EmailAddress1="asifghafoor@my.web.pk" />
<Contact FirstName="Rameez" LastName="Ali" EmailAddress1="rameezali@my.web.pk" />
<Contact FirstName="Aneel" LastName="Maqsood" EmailAddress1="aneelmaqsood@my.web.pk" />
</OutLookContact>'

--Create an internal representation of the XML document.

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @doc

-- Execute a SELECT statement that uses the OPENXML rowset provider.

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(FirstName VARCHAR(250),LastName VARCHAR(250),Email1 VARCHAR(250))  

INSERT INTO @Temp(FirstName,LastName,Email1)



SELECT *

FROM OPENXML (@idoc, '/OutLookContact/Contact',1)

WITH (FirstName varchar(50),LastName varchar(50),EmailAddress1 varchar(50))


select FirstName,LastName,Email1 from @Temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put the xml into another temp table, and then do an insert statement from there:

http://www.lockergnome.com/sqlsquirrel/2008/05/23/how-to-turn-imported-xml-into-a-relational-format-in-sql-server-2005/